# filter on Opencart not working correctly

Tags: php, search, attributes, opencart

i am working on a website http://autoreifenplatz.at .
on the frontend we have a search block in which you can search for product attributes. After adding a second import-function (i believe this is causing the search not working) the search for attributes (like breite=width or Höhe=height), no results show up, it seems it cannot find the attributes to show any results. Now when you choose Reifenmarke (Brand) it is working.
Does anybody have any idea as to why or point me in the right direction to solve this? (or maybe have a solution for this).

Comment: Can you show your form handling code?

Comment: would love too, but everything is going with plugins and vqmod. i cannot place all the code of different files as i dont know what is using what and where. i could give some access to the ftp if that makes it some easier...